# Python how to add more than one input in the requests.get url

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm currently doing a webscraping lyrics project as a beginner, and I've run into an issue.

I want the user to input the first letter of an artists name and the full artists name, but I'm not quite sure how to deal with the slashes in the URL. Here is the code:

```
from bs4 import beautifulSoup as bs
import requests


    def main():
        lyrics_getter()
    
    
    def artist_input():
        first_artist_name = input(
            "Please enter the first letter of the artists name: ")
    
        artist_name = input("Please enter the name of an artist: ")
        if not artist_name.isalpha():
            print("Please enter only alphabetical characters for the artist.")
        else:
            print(artist_name)
            print("Compiling lyrics for: ", artist_name,
                  sep="")
    
    
    def lyrics_getter():
    
        artist_input()
        website = requests.get('https://www.azlyrics.com/',
                               first_artist_name, '/', artist_name, '.html') # ERROR OCCURS HERE
    
    
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

In the `lyrics_getter()` function, I am trying to use the user inputs from `artist_input()` in the url, but I'm getting an unexpected argument error.

I think it's mainly due to the fact that I split the url, but I am not really sure how to go about it. Here is an example of what I am trying to achieve:

https://www.azlyrics.com/j/jayz.html

Any tips?

Thanks!

Comment: Instead of `,` which passes multiple arguments to `requests.get()` use either `+` to concatenate the string, or us `os.path.join()`

Comment: `'https://www.azlyrics.com/' + first_artist_name + '/' + artist_name + '.html'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There a gazillion ways to do this one, my preferred method is by putting f before the string method, as it looks the cleanest to me imo.

Put "f" before the string and use {} to put variables right into the string.

```
website = requests.get(f'https://www.azlyrics.com/{first_artist_name}/{artist_name}.html')
```

I hope having another option helps :)

Comment: Thank you! It is definitely nice to have other options.

Answer (score 1):

In python you can use [format()](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_format.asp) function.

> 'https://www.azlyrics.com/{}/{}.html'.format(first_artist_name,artist_name)

So ideally your code should be

```
website = requests.get('https://www.azlyrics.com/{}/{}.html'.format(first_artist_name,artist_name))
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use `f string` method!

```
website = requests.get(f'https://www.azlyrics.com/{first_artist_name}/{artist_name}.html')
```